# Parameter count mismatch on stub with lambda expression using Moq

Tags: unit-testing, lambda, moq

I get a 'parameter count mismatch' TargetParameterCountException when I want to test my Tenant repository:

The interface:

```
public interface ITenantRepository
{
    IQueryable<Tenant> Get(Expression<Func<Tenant, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<Tenant>, IOrderedQueryable<Tenant>> orderBy = null,
    string includeProperties = null);
}
```

The test code:

```
var TenantRepository = new Mock<ITenantRepository>();

TenantRepository
    .Setup(p => p.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Tenant, bool>>>(),
        It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Tenant>,IOrderedQueryable<Tenant>>>() ,
        It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(new Func<Expression<Func<Tenant, bool>>,
       IQueryable<Tenant>>(expr => Tenants.Where(expr.Compile()).AsQueryable()));

Tenant TestTenant = TenantRepository.Object.Get(
      t => t.TenantID == Tenant2.TenantID,
      null,
      null).FirstOrDefault();
```

The error occurs on the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution for the correct parameters:

```
TenantRepository.Setup(p => p.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Tenant, bool>>>(),
                                  It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<Tenant>, IOrderedQueryable<Tenant>>>(),
                                  It.IsAny<string>()))
                .Returns(
                         (Expression<Func<Tenant, bool>> expr, 
                          Func<IQueryable<Tenant>, IOrderedQueryable<Tenant>> orderBy,
                          string includeProperties) => Tenants.Where(expr.Compile()).AsQueryable());
```

Comment: Thanks for the code! Think you should get more upvotes

Comment: I wish i could know how you are able to figure this out! I don't this it exists in any documentation.. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem resides in the return type of your mocked object: according to your interface, the method Get should return an `IQueryable`, but you are mocking it to return a `Func<Expression<Func<Tenant, bool>>, IQueryable<Tenant>>` instead.

Just keep in mind that *returning a function is different from returning its result*; in this case, you should create an expected `IQueryable` object and just tell Moq to return it. It doesn't make much sense to mock something using its expected behaviour - which looks like what you are trying to do here.